# Multi-Tenant PostgreSQL Auth Schema Design (Users, Roles, Teams, Permissions, Subscriptions, Stripe)

Tags: postgresql, database-design, authentication, multi-tenant, authorization

I am designing a multi-tenant database schema and specifically stuck on the Authentication (AuthN) and Authorization (AuthZ) alongside with App subscription. I think I should pretty good after that. My preliminary schema. I haven't found many resources on this even though I believe what I have below is very stereotypical/common.

Note: I am leaving out fields like `created_at`, `updated_at`, and tables like `EMAIL_VERIFICATON_CODE`, `PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN` for brevity.

**Business Rules:**

- A `TENANT` represents the highest level grouping. Represents workspace/business unit/project.
- A `USER` can have be part of many tenants with a different `ROLE` at each. (May be an `OWNER` at one and just a `USER` on another.
- `OWNER` role has permissions to do anything. It is not effected by `APP_PERMISSIONS`
- `USER` role's permission are effected by `APP_PERMISSION`
- A `TEAM` is specific within each `TENANT`
- An `APP` represents a SaaS subscription through Stripe (Ex: inventory app, human resource app).
- An `APP` has many `APP_PERMISSION`s associated with it. (Ex: create product)
- A `TEAM` and `USER` can have many `APP_PERMISSION`'s.
- A `TEAM` is just an easy way to group `APP_PERMISSON`s to associate with many `USER`
- A `USER`'s cumulative permissions are ones directly associated with each `USER` and `TEAM`'s its on for that specific `TENANT`.
- Either `OWNER` or `USER`s with `invite` permission will be able to invite other `USER`s to the TENANT.

**ISSUES Not Resolved**

- How should `APP` be related to `TENANT` or `USER`? How to setup that `USER` that has the role of `OWNER` of a `TENANT` is responsible for the `APP` subscription. What happens when there are multiple `OWNER`'s in the same tenant?
- What happens if a `USER` only has role of `USER` with one tenant through invite. Then gets kicked out of that tenant? Standalone `USER` account without any association to a `TENANT`?
- In order to solve the above problems, maybe I need to add another ROLE type? `ADMIN` is not effected by `APP_PERMISSION` and can do anything. The difference between `ADMIN` is that `OWNER` role is just who is responsible for app subscription.
- I don't want to force all `USER`s to be an owner of a `TENANT`
- Not sure if better way to model `APP_PERMISSION` and `APP_PERMISSION_ACTION`, don't feel to good about it. May be action should just be free text and get rid of lookup table `APP_PERMISSION_ACTION`.
- Because only `USER` role is affected by `APP_PERMISSION`, should I actually model as supertype subtype? But then again, what happens if a `USER` with role `USER` has `APP_PERMISSION`s then get promoted to `OWNER`? vice versa? Shouldn't lose the `APP_PERMISSION` data it had.

**USER**

- id UUID PK
- fullName TEXT NOT NULL
- email TEXT NOT NULL
- email_verified BOOLEAN
- password TEXT NOT NULL

**SESSION**

- id TEXT PK
- user_id UUID NOT NULL(references USER.id)
- expires_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL

**TENANT**

- id UUID PK
- name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE

**ROLE**

- id SMALLSERIAL PK
- name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
  Values will be `OWNER` and `USER`

**TENANT_MEMBERSHIP**

- user_id UUID CPK (references USER.id)
- role_id SMALLINT CPK(references ROLE.id)
- tenant_id UUID CPK (references TENANT.id)
- app_permission_id UUID CPK (references APP_PERMISSION.id)

**USER_TEAM_MEMBERSHIP**

- user_id UUID CPK (references USER.id)
- team_id UUID CPK (references TEAM.id)
- app_permission_id UUID CPK (references APP_PERMISSION.id)

**TEAM**

- id UUID PK
- name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
- tenant_id UUID (references TENANT.id)

**USER_INVITE**

- user_id UUID CPK (references USER.id)
- tenant_id UUID CPK (references TENANT.id)
- expires_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL

**APP** (Stripe Product data)

- id TEXT PK
- name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
- ...other stripe data

Values will be `Inventory`, `Human Resources`

**APP_PERMISSION**

- id SERIAL PK
- name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
- app_id TEXT (references APP.id)
- resource TEXT NOT NULL
- app_permission_action_id INTEGER (references APP_PERMISSION_ACTION.id)

**APP_PERMISSION_ACTION**

- id SERIAL PK
- name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
  Values will be `create`, `update`, `read`, `delete`, `invite`, etc

**APP_SUBSCRIPTION** (Stripe Billing Subscription data)

- id TEXT PK
- app_id TEXT (references APP.id)
- ...other stripe data
- How to relate this?

**STRIPE_CUSTOMER** (Stripe Customer data)

- id TEXT PK
- user_id UUID NOT NULL(references USER.id)
- ...other stripe data

All entities specific to tenant

**TENANT_SPECIFIC_ENTIY**

- id UUID CPK
- ..other entity
- tenant_id UUID CPK (references TENANT.id)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through this, there seems to be some convolution around permissions and roles. Specifically in roles-based authentication, we have `users`, `roles` and `permissions`. Users are given roles, realized through `users_roles` and roles are affirmatively granted permission through `roles_permissions` relations.

In your work, the `user_roles` metaphor is given by `TENANT_MEMBERSHIP`, but what links `ROLE` to `APP_PERMISSION`?

Your first question:

> How should APP be related to TENANT or USER? How to setup that USER that has the role of OWNER of a TENANT is responsible for the APP subscription. What happens when there are multiple OWNER's in the same tenant?

In my opinion, the APP/TENANT question boils down to one choice: Do all TENANTs have access to all apps?

- If yes, then you only need a `ROLE_APP_PERMISSION` table, and the couplet of (ROLE_ID, APP_PERMISSION_ID) would represent a role bearing a specific permission
- If no, then  will need the a 3-way relation `TENANT_ROLE_APP_PERMISSION` and the triplet (TENANT_ID, ROLE_ID, APP_PERMISSION_ID) appears to be the correct relation.

Next Question

> What happens if a USER only has role of USER with one tenant through invite. Then gets kicked out of that tenant? Standalone USER account without any association to a TENANT?

Similarly, what if a user has all of their `ROLES` revoked?
Well, then they would have no permission, because `PERMISSION` are given to `ROLES`, and `ROLES` are given to `USERS`.

So, if a user is given `ROLES` by way of membership in a `TENANT`, then a `USER` without a `TENANT` has no `ROLE` and thus no `PERMISSION`.

Question 3:

> In order to solve the above problems, maybe I need to add another ROLE type? ADMIN is not effected by APP_PERMISSION and can do anything. The difference between ADMIN is that OWNER role is just who is responsible for app subscription.

No, Do not create an `ADMIN` role that is "not affected by app permissions". Instead, create an admin role that has all relevant permissions. If you need to distingush between an `OWNER` AND `ADMIN`, grant the `ADMIN` **ROLE** a greater `PERMISSION`.

> I don't want to force all USERs to be an owner of a TENANT

You should not have to. Rather:

- A user can have 0 or more TENANTS
- A user can have 0 or more ROLES

> Not sure if better way to model APP_PERMISSION and APP_PERMISSION_ACTION, don't feel to good about it. May be action should just be free text and get rid of lookup table APP_PERMISSION_ACTION.

I am unclear why the `APP_PERMISSION_ACTION` table has a foreign key relation on itself. Perhaps you can offer more details on the design and intent here.

> Because only USER role is affected by APP_PERMISSION, should I actually model as supertype subtype? But then again, what happens if a USER with role USER has APP_PERMISSIONs then get promoted to OWNER? vice versa? Shouldn't lose the APP_PERMISSION data it had.

IMO, you should instead maintain a clear boundary between USERS, ROLES, and PERMISSION and not convolute them with the typing noted above. If a user has both a `ROLE` and additional permissions, something is awry; Instead of giving a user additional permission, you should give the user additional roles.

That speaks the the idea that how we have divined ROLES may need to be rethought. Perhaps each `APP` should have 2 roles, APP/OWNER and APP/USER, and the user is granted either or none.

Either way, your application code should ONLY be looking at PERMISSIONS when determining access and control, and NOT making decisions like `IF (USER IS ADMIN) ...` but prefer `IF (USER HAS PERMISSION_XYZ)`. The `PERMISSION` should be given to the `ROLE` and the `USER` should be granted `ROLES`

For more on RBAC, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

For more on Discresionary Access Control, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control

Comment: So I wasn’t going with traditional nomenclature of RBAC. The function of roles is generally to group permissions. But I instead did this with teams. I also got inspiration from AWS permission system. They allow directly assigning a permission to a user, although, they recommend assigning to a role first. Just wanted to handle edge case in someone needed to add perm to user. Permission action was more about bout creating a lookup table for integrity, CRUD operations. But then again, I got thrown a thorn with”invite” an action user

Comment: oooh - I missed teams, though that seems to further muddy the definition of roles. moreso than permissions.

Comment: In divining this model, perhaps it is best to start from the other end of the system: Think of oneself as the application developer developing a CRUD endpoint:
- How will I express granular permission to a particular resource? How will I then provide (ie migrate SQL) existing roles and/or users with this permission? How will I pair a ROLE to a particular action and do so in a consistent way across the application? Should the permission be expressed in terms of ROLE A can perform ACTION B, or rather than USER A can perform ACTION B? I would opt for the latter as this keeps perm semantics clear